# Call a PL/SQL package from shell script - Error "identifier must be declared"

Tags: bash, oracle

am calling a plsql package from shell script as

```js
sqlplus -s <<! 
   $userpass
    set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
   exec POEXT.PO_ACK_UPDATE("$worfile",$ftpvendornum,"$org_code",$req_id,"$ftpgrp","$vendor_name");
     exit;
!
```

The value of the parameters as follows

```js
worfile=R12POAUS220171025@230307.ZIP
ftpvendornum=15163
org_code=US2
req_id=53004007
ftpgrp=DCU
vendor_name=Empty
```

when i run - I get an error message like below

```js
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 35:
PLS-00201: identifier 'R12POAUS220171025@230307.ZIP' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I executed the same block in sqldeveloper using anonymous block its getting executed.

can someone help me to figure out what could be the possible issue?

Comment: This `worfile=R12POAUS220171025@230307.ZIP` should be like `worfile='R12POAUS220171025@230307.ZIP'`. Enclosed with `'`

Comment: Actually I pasted that from Log.. not from the code .. for the readers refereence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is it when you write the statement with single ' around the parameters?

```
exec POEXT.PO_ACK_UPDATE('$worfile',$ftpvendornum,'$org_code',$req_id,'$ftpgrp','$vendor_name');
```

Comment: well.. I need to try that.. there are other package calls also happening in this host file. all have double quotes. But Let me try this option